# I am getting an error on table population from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am attempting to populate a table from json data... I am getting an error message on inspect that states the $ is undefined and the resulting table is empty. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Here is the html:

```
    <html manifest="trade.appcache">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js" rel="javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" rel="jquery" ></script>

<title>Top Trades</title>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;padding: 0; display:none;">
<div id="deepbkg"></div>
<div id="fullscreen">
    <audio autoplay><source src="audio/trade.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<div id="system" class="mySlides" style="display: block;">
    <table id="systems">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="systems"> 
                <h1>Top System Trades</h1>
                </th>
                <th>
                <div>
                    <h2>Trade Value</h2>
                </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="images/gamestop.png" style="width: 80%;" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="games" class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
    <table id="games">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="systems">
                <h1>
                    Top Game Trades 
                </h1>
                </th>
                <th>
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        PRO 
                    </h2>
                </div>
                </th>
                <th>
                <div>
                    <h3>
                        Regular Value 
                    </h3>
                </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="electronics" class="mySlides" style="display: none;">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="systems">
                <h1>
                    Top Electronics Trades 
                </h1>
                </th>
                <th>
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        Trade Value 
                    </h2>
                </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="cube">
    <img src="images/cube.gif" style="width: 80%" />
</div>
```

```
<script src="js/divslide.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
var genericAJAXRequest =     function(jsonFeedURL,paramData,callbackSuccess,callbackFailure,renderFunc) {
    var paramData = (paramData !== undefined) ? paramData:{};
        $.ajax({
            url: jsonFeedURL,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: paramData,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
                // On success do this
                callbackSuccess(data,renderFunc);
        })
        .fail(function(e) {
            // on failure do these things
            console.log("error");
            console.log(e);
            callbackFailure(e);
        }); 
}

    // If we get a good feed do this
    var goodFeed = function(data,callback) {
        console.log("Loaded Feed!");
        console.log(data);
        callback(data)
    }


    var badFeed = function(data) {
        console.log("Did not load feed - error!");
        console.log(data);
    }


    var dispSystem = function(data) {


        $("#system table h1").text("Top System Trades");
        $("#system table h2").text("Trade Value");
        console.log(data.TopSystemTrades[0].name);

        var row = "";
        var loop = 0;
        var len = data.TopSystemTrades.length;
        var rowClass = "cost";
        for (loop = 0; loop < len; loop++) {
            row += '<tr><td class="title">'+data.TopSystemTrades[loop].name+'';
            row += ' <span>'+data.TopSystemTrades[loop].pf+'</span></td>';
            row += '<td class="'+rowClass+'">$'+parseFloat(data.TopSystemTrades[loop].price).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()+'</td></tr>';
        }
        $("#system table tbody").html(row);
        console.log(row);

        $("body").fadeIn(1000);

    }


    var dispGames = function(data) {
        var table = $("#games");

        $("#games table h1").text("Top Game Trades");
        $("#games table h2").text("PRO");
        $("#games table h3").text("Regular Value");

        var row = "";
        var loop = 0;
        var len = data.TopGameTrades.length;
        for (loop = 0; loop < len; loop++) {
            row += '<tr><td class="title">'+data.TopGameTrades[loop].name+'';
            row += ' <span>'+data.TopGameTrades[loop].pf+'</span></td>';
            row += '<td class="cost">$'+parseFloat(data.TopGameTrades[loop].reg).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()+'</td>';
            row += '<td class="cost">$'+parseFloat(data.TopGameTrades[loop].pro).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()+'</td></tr>';

        }
        $("#games table tbody").html(row);
        console.log(row);

        $("body").fadeIn();

    }

    var dispElectronics = function(data) {

        var table = $("#electronics");
        $("#electronics table h1").text("Top Electronics Trades");
        $("#electronics table h2").text("Trade Value");

        var row = "";
        var loop = 0;
        var len = data.TopElectronicsTrades.length;
        for (loop = 0; loop < len; loop++) {
            row += '<tr><td class="title">'+data.TopElectronicsTrades[loop].name+'';
            row += ' <span>'+data.TopElectronicsTrades[loop].pf+'</span></td>';
            row += '<td class="cost">$'+parseFloat(data.TopElectronicsTrades[loop].price).toFixed(2).toLocaleString()+'</td></tr>';
        }
        $("#electronics table tbody").html(row);
        console.log(row);

        $("body").fadeIn();
    }


// Define our urls for the 3 different feeds
var topSystemsFeedURL = "data/top_system_trades_gde.json";  
var topGameFeedURL = "data/top_game_trades_gde.json";   
var topElectronicsFeedURL = "data/top_electronics_trades_gde.json"; 

// Make three different calls to load the json data from the urls, and render them to the html
genericAJAXRequest(topSystemsFeedURL, null, goodFeed, badFeed, dispSystem); 
genericAJAXRequest(topGameFeedURL, null, goodFeed, badFeed, dispGames); 
genericAJAXRequest(topElectronicsFeedURL, null, goodFeed, badFeed, dispElectronics);    

});
```

Comment: Include jquery in your page.

Comment: I have it linked.

Comment: Please post your complete HTML code here.

Comment: I have edited the code to show entire page.

Comment: try include JQuery before leaflet.js

Comment: Thank you, but same result.